# How to convert a string with an HTML code into a working HTML code (in Ruby or Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby

I am putting following code into a Ruby array:

```
@data << "=> <div><a href='/company/#{d.name}'>See profile</a></div>"
```

I've tried this:

```
@data << "=> <div><a href='/company/#{d.name}'>See profile</a></div>".html_safe
```

But it didn't help me.

I am passing the `@data` to JSON (`@data.to_json`), so then in the JS, I would need to have the label **See profile** as a link, not a text. So I tried

```
label1 = variable_with_the_string_from_above.html();
```

But this didn't help me out too... In the JS variable is the **See profile** still like a plain text only (`<div><a href='/company/#{d.name}'>See profile</a></div>`), not like an HTML link.

How to do that?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
var htmlArray = ["<div><a href='/company/#{d.name}'>See profile</a></div>"];
```

To inject into the HTML:

```
document.write(htmlArray[0]);
```

If you are passing the {d.name} as a variable, try AngularJS.

Create a controller and scope ->

```
App.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) 
{
$scope.dname = dname(); etc. 
 }]);
```

and than in your html or js:

```
var htmlArray = ["<div><a href='/company/{{dname}}'>See profile</a></div>"];
```

Make sure the array is within the range of your controller scope!

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
...
</div>
```

An easier way to do this would be just to use AngularJS routing:

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/companyOne', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/c1.html',
        controller: 'c1'
    }).
      when('/companyTwo', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/c2.html',
        controller: 'c2'
      }).

      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/default'
      });
}]);
```